# When a weaker computer wins

Tags: algorithms, memory-management

Consider the following algorithm:

1. run algorithm A until a solution or out of memory
2. run algorithm B

Then if A does not solve the problem, a computer with less memory has an advantage.

This could be solved by running A and B in parallel, but then the resulting parallel algorithm could be renamed A' and run:

1. run algorithm A' until a solution or out of memory
2. run algorithm B'

for some algorithm B', possibly producing a similar result (out of memroy is an advantage).

Also, more generally, if an algorithm goes in a wrong direction, a weaker computer has an advantage.

My questions:

- Could you describe systematically such cases when weaker computers have advantage?
- Could you refer to some articles or books (preferrably open access) on this topic?
- What's about a generic solution of this "trouble"?

Comment: Why is that an advantage?

Comment: Isn't it an artificial challenge? You designed an algorithm where a computer with less memory is faster. But I could also say, measure the computer's clock speed, then square that number, then do nothing that many times, then run algorithm A. Doesn't that mean slower computers have an advantage?

Comment: @user253751 I am mainly about the case when weaker computers _naturally_ have an advantage. When a mathematician chooses a wrong algorithm and because of this it solves faster on a weaker computer because out-of-memory is an advantage.

Comment: You could find a wrong algorithm where anything is an advantage. You could find an algorithm that works better if the webcam can see purple stuff.